# Iterate through Object Variables efficiently with Python

Tags: python, loops, oop

I have an object with a large number of variables which all return Pass, Fail or NA.  I'm trying to summarize the results to return the total number of Passes, etc.

I'd like to do something like the following.

```
    list_of_checks = [check1, check2, check3]
    for check in list_of_checks:
        for a_object in list_of_objects:
            if a_object.check == "Pass"
                pass_counter += 1
            elif a_object.check == "Fail"
                fail_counter += 1
```

This doesn't work.  I get a traceback because a_object doesn't have an attribute "check"

Is this possible or do I have to brute force it?

Comment: Is the _check_ variable optional? You can use _getattr_ or a try/except block.

Comment: It seems like not all the objects have the check variable. Since you have an option for it to be NA, why not initialize every object with NA, and then change it to Pass/Fail whenever you need to?

Comment: The data set is a large number of network devices, some of the checks are not applicable to all devices.  I'm including the na in the summary report to make it clear that all devices were included in the check.  Totals (P, F, NA) should equal total number of devices as a sanity check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the variable `check` to access an object's members in that way. You could however do something more like:

```
if getattr(a_object, check) == "Pass":
```

These two lines are equivalent:

```
if getattr(a_object, "check1") == "Pass":

if a_object.check1 == "Pass":
```

Comment: @user3641109 Maybe because using `getattr` is generally viewed as sort of dirty. Not because its a bad function but because usually its presence is a code smell. But it *does* work.

Comment: This answer addressed the specific question.  Just because a program was poorly constructed doesn't mean the answer should be "rewrite your program".  In my case, I had a deadline and this requirement came up late.  I needed to get it done, whether it was "dirty" or not.  The world is not perfect, there are deadlines.  Should/Could have the program have been written a different way, definitely.  Does this mean that the answer to the specific question deserves a down vote.  No!

Comment: If I spent all of my time re-doing things the 'right' way, I'd never get anything done ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use getattr to check for attributes programatically, but cannot reference function that is a member of an instance by using a common label bound to class members. Using getattr requires that the name of the members you want to reference be given as strings:

```
list_of_checks = ['check1', 'check2', 'check3']
for check in list_of_checks:
    for a_object in list_of_objects:
        maybe = getattr(a_object, check)
        if maybe == "Pass":
            pass_counter += 1
        elif maybe == "Fail":
            fail_counter += 1
```

If not every object has a "check1" or whatever, then you will get exceptions that can be caught with

```
try:
    if getattr(obj, check) == "Pass"
        # and so on...
except AttributeError:
    # Do whatever
```

**BUT**

Generally speaking, whenever I see a situation where I think I need a conditional *inside* of a `try...except` clause I am *usually* looking at a situation where I've just created an X-Y problem for myself, and need to think back further up in the code structure to find a way to not need these checks in the first place.

For example, why are you not asking your objects if they have passed or failed, and if they have have them notify the score-keeper objects. Or something along those lines.